# java.net.MalformedURLException at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, url

I am trying to make a distributed web crawler in which the initial urls is given by the user in a textfield and the crawled urls are displayed on server and client consoles when the search button is pressed.
My code is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;;
import java.lang.*;


class UCDemo implements ActionListener {
    static String n1;
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel p1;
    JLabel l1;
    JLabel l2;
    JTextField t1;
    JButton b1;

    public void showFrame() {
        f1 = new JFrame("Web Crawler");
        p1 = new JPanel();
        f1.setSize(800, 800);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setBackground(Color.pink);
        f1.getContentPane().add(p1);
        l1 = new JLabel("Distributed Web Crawler");
        t1 = new JTextField(100);
        b1 = new JButton("Start");
        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            n1 = t1.getText();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, FileNotFoundException, NotBoundException, NullPointerException {
        int c = 0;
        UCDemo obj = new UCDemo();
        obj.showFrame();
        Document document = null;
        URL hp = new URL(n1);
        URLConnection hpcon = hp.openConnection();
        String dispServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/DispServer";
        DispServerIntf dispServerIntf = (DispServerIntf) Naming.lookup(dispServerURL);
        try {
            document = Jsoup.parse(hp, 3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Element element : document.getElementsByTag("a")) {
            c++;
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(hp.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("te.html");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            if (c <= 7) {
                Document doc_tmp = null;
                URL hp_tmp = new URL(element.attr("href"));
                URLConnection hpcontmp = hp_tmp.openConnection();
                /** try
                 {
                 doc_tmp=Jsoup.parse(hp_tmp,3000);
                 }
                 catch(IOException e)
                 {e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 for (Element ele: doc_tmp.getElementsByTag("a"))
                 {
                 System.out.println(ele.attr("href"));
                 }**/
                ReadableByteChannel rbc_tmp = Channels.newChannel(hp_tmp.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos_tmp = new FileOutputStream("te" + c + ".html");
                fos_tmp.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc_tmp, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            } else {
                dispServerIntf.send(element.attr("href"));
            }
        }
        /** BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(hpcon.getInputStream()));
         String inputline;
         while((inputline=in.readLine())!=null)
         System.out.println(inputline);
         in.close();**/
    }
}
```

But when I run this code the GUI is displayed properly but it does not wait for the initial URL and throws MalformedURLException....Unknown Source.
Please guide where is the problem in code.

Comment: What does the error say? (To the tune of "The Fox")

Comment: You are showing the frame and then going straight to the implementation. That's not how GUI works. It is event-based. You are supposed to have the operations started from the `actionPerformed()`, not from `main`. And please note it's very bad practice to have `main` throw anything. You are supposed to handle all exceptions with `try...catch`.

Comment: Stack trace please. Evidently `n1` is stlll null, so you can't construct your `URL.` Nothing to do with RMI whatsoever. Or Swing. Please think about how to ask questions here. This isn't adequate. You've omitted essential information and you've posted a lot of completely irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

First, may I recommend you read Clean Code. This is so unreadable it took me ages to find what you're even talking about.

As to the problem itself, you're creating the URL `hp` in the main method. This line occurs before the actionPerformed function is invoked, therefore the string `n1` is `null`. That's why you're getting an error.